# Attribute sets - why not just use default set?

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

A really basic question, but I've read a lot about not just using the default attributes set. What are the benefits (both the the customer and in the back end) of having multiple attribute sets by product type, apart from LH filters?

Answer (score 2):

Attribute sets are actually very important. It's crucial for performance (especially the layered navigation) that your products only have attributes relevant to their type.

Here is a bit more reading about it:
http://inchoo.net/magento/importance-of-planning-attribute-sets/

Comment: Thanks for this. We have an extension (Amasty) for the front end filters so would this overcome it? Is there anything we won't be able to do if we stick with the default attributes?

Comment: There is nothing you won't be able to do, but you will find that your back-end  won't be well organized and that the whole experience won't be as optimised as it could be. I don't think there would be any issue with Amasty but I wouldn't really recommend their module anyway

Comment: @Mayers curious what you have against improved navigation extension?

Comment: I think the layered navigation is like the checkout, the less you touch it, the better. There are some good LN extensions out there, but the one from Amasty wouldn't get my votes

Comment: @Mayers I've been using for 2 years. Never really had problems, and seems to be one that other companies will make their extensions work with. But I agree messing with layered nav is a bit of a loaded gun.

Comment: @ladle3000 I have seen what's under the hood, and not a big fan of how some stuff have been implemented, and I dread some impact on performance. But I don't disagree, it seems to do the job.

Comment: @Mayers Quite honestly it's one that always concerns me, and feels 'sloppy'